# libspotify: music_delivery callback not firing

Tags: haskell, spotify, ffi

I've successfully loaded a Spotify track from a playlist (verified by tracing the track name out to the screen), passed it to be played using `sp_session_player_load` and `sp_session_player_play(sess, 1)`.

However my `music_delivery` callback is never called (I've have some trace in there to show when it is). The [libspotify FAQ](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/faq/) seems to imply that it will be invoked by an internal thread inside the API and I do not need to invoke `sp_session_process_events` to start the streaming.

My application is singly threaded so I'm assuming there is no locking issue in my code.

---

Sources:

libspotify Haskell binding:
https://github.com/mrehayden1/libspotify
(You will need libspotify installed to get this to compile: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/#download)

The application code:
https://github.com/mrehayden1/harmony

Comment: You're going to need to show the code, and probably the haskell binding you're using. Could be anything really.

Comment: Just edited the question with links to the sources. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ideas:

> I do not need to invoke `sp_session_process_events` to start the streaming.

This is somewhat correct, however, you *must* trigger `sp_session_process_events` when you get a `notify_main_thread` callback — this comes in on another thread, so you need to correctly delegate this back to your main thread to make the call.

Since you mention you only have a single thread, make sure you're not spinning in a tight loop somewhere — something like `while (!sp_track_is_loaded(track)) {}` — since a lot of work in libspotify goes on in the thread you make the calls on, doing this will cause libspotify to be unable to do any work, and everything will grind to a halt.

> passed it to be played using `sp_session_player_load` and `sp_session_player_play(sess, 1)`.

What are the results of these calls? Loading metadata isn't the same as loading for playback, so you might be getting `SP_ERROR_IS_LOADING` back from the play call. In addition, the track might not be playable for some other reason, so the error is important.

---

If you're still having trouble, the problem may be in the bindings or elsewhere in your code. Check the jukebox example that comes with libspotify for an example C implementation of playback.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: notify_main_thread. I will try that to see what it does.
The results of `sp_session_play_load` and `sp_session_player_play` are both SP_ERROR_OK.
Please see my revised question for the Haskell sources. 
I deliberately tried to avoid tight loops with calls to threadDelay.